# É possível usar um "SOMARPRODUTO" para calcular valores em varias planilhas?

Tags: microsoft-excel

Tenho umas tabelas com nomes de lojas e gostaria de saber a somas de valores destas lojas que esta em diferentes planilhas. É possivel fazer isso usando o "SOMARPRODUTO" ou "SOMASE"?
Tentei isso mas não da certo:

```
=SOMARPRODUTO(('2014:2015'!C3:C3069=Tabela1[@LOJA])*('2014:2015'!D3:D3069="RESULTADO")*('2014:2015'!E3:E3069))
```

Answer (score 1):

É possível sim. Basta você começar a escrever a formulá, e quando quiser o valor de outro arquivo (ele tem que estar aberto) basta clicar em uma célula dele, automaticamente ele vai fazer a referencia. É praticamente igual a fazer uma formulá no mesmo arquivo.

Duas imagens para ajudar a entender.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

No youtube também se acha alguns vídeos ensinando. Assiste pelo menos até a metade [desse.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uJC48z7YkZ4)

Comment: Obrigado ricardo, mas na verdade não é isso. A ídeia não retomar valores de outro arquivo e sim de uma outra planilha. Se você reparar na formula eu comparo um Range "C3:C3069" tanto da planilha 2014 quanto da planilha 2015.

Comment: É a mesma coisa. Só que em vez de clicar na planilha de outro arquivo você clica em outra planilha do mesmo arquivo

Comment: Cara isso eu entendo, o problema é pegar o range especifico nas diferentes planilhas. Na minha formula mostra eu tento o seguinte: Some o range E3:E3069 da planilha 2014 e 2015 onde no range de C3:C3069 de 2014 e 2015 seja contenha uma loja especifica e o range de D3:D3069 tanto em 2014 como 2015 contenha "RESULTADO". Note que eu posso adicionar uma nova planilha, por exemplo 2013, como o mesmo formato e a soma passaria a incluir esse mesmo valor, por isso coloco ":" entre o nome das duas planilhas quando especifico os ranges "'2014:2015'!D3:D3069"